# Passing parameters to less file in command line

Tags: dotless

I am using dotless.compiler.exe in my solution and passing below command in post build event of solution properties.

$(SolutionDir)\packages\dotless.1.1.0\Tools\dotless.Compiler.exe -m "$(ProjectDir)\content*.less" "$(ProjectDir)\content*.css"

Question is can I pass some parameters to less files in this command?

suppose I have a variable called **@back-color:red** declared in my less file.

can I pass something like "@back-color:green" in this command line and get respective css?